# What is the appropriate def. of $\sigma$-($\Sigma^1_1$) measurable.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, definition, descriptive-set-theory

I know that borel measurable means that the inverse image of a Borel set (or open set) is measurable.

Edit: I am speaking of the sigma algebra generated by the analytic sets in a top. space.

Comment: Sorry, my only internet access is on my phone and its not working out for me.  I fixed the errors.

Comment: I'm not sure where the difficulty is. Given a set $X$ and a sigma algebra $\cal B$, we say that $f\colon X\to\Bbb R$ is $\cal B$-measurable if the preimage of a Borel set is in $\cal B$. Now replace $X$ by a standard Polish space and $\cal B$ by $\sigma(\Sigma^1_1)$.

Comment: I just needed the definition.  I was unsure of whether the prefix on measurable was a change on the sets being pulled back or the option you gave above in your definition.